# JDBC datasource using jar file in WEB-INF/lib instead of creating a new Jboss module

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, jboss7.x

As i understand it, with JBOSS 7, the data source is configured by creating a new module in `$JBOSS_HOME/modules`. This process includes adding the jar file for the jdbc driver to be used by the datasourced to be configured.

Is there any way i can configure a datasource without having to create a new module?

My web application has the MySQL Connector JDBC driver in the war file (in `WEB-INF/lib` - Included as part of the maven build). Wouldnt creating a new module result is a class conflict as this requires copying the jar file in the `modules/../main/ folder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, with MySQL at least, you have to create it as a module. With compliant JDBC 4 you can deploy it as a JAR.

I don't know the details, but in JBoss AS 7.1.0 you will be able to use the -ds.xml files to describe your connection. There is some documentation on it [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration#DataSourceconfiguration-Deploymentof%5Cds.xmlfiles)